# Custom URL for different items with Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm doing a website about League of Legends. I choosed wordpress to do it. Now I'm doing the champions page, and to do it I'm using Handlebar.js (into Wordpress page) to have a single template with whom I can showing dynamically all champions specifics and details. I post here the codes (HTML into WP page, and Javascript):

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Champion</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main-container"></div>
    <script id="info-champ-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#listItem 0 0 champions}}
            <div class="esterno">
                <h1>{{name}} Overview</h1>
                <div id="img-champion"><img src="{{icon}}" alt="img-{{name}}"/>
                </div>
                <div id="info-champion">
                    <p id="champ-name">{{name}}</p>
                    <div id="inf">{{ip}}</div>
                    <div id="riot">{{rp}}</div>
                    <br><p id="champ-title">{{title}}</p>
                </div>
                <div id="role-champion">
                    <img id="img-role" src="immagini  {{roleimg}}"/>
                    <p id="name-role">{{role}}</p>
                </div>
                <p id="champ-lore">{{{lore}}}</p>
            </div>{{/listItem}}</script>
            <!-- JavaScript***********************-->
            <script src="js/champions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
            <script src="js/js.main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript files:

js.main.js

```
var source = document.getElementById("info-champ-template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
Handlebars.registerHelper('listItem', function (from, to, context, options){
    var item = "";
    if(to==0){
        item = item + options.fn(context[from]);
    }
    else{
        for (var i=from, j=to;i<j;i++){
            item=item+options.fn(context[i]);
        }
    }
    return item;
});
var output=template(data1);document.getElementById("main-container").innerHTML=output;
```

champions.js (similiar to JSON file)

```
var data1={"champions":[
    {name: "Champ1",
    img: "Alistar.png",
    ip: 1350,
    rp: 585,
    role: "Support",
    roleimg: "Bot.png",
    title: "il minotauro",
    lore: "Champion Lore"},

    name: "Champ2",
    img: "Alistar.png",
    ip: 1350,
    rp: 585,
    role: "Support",
    roleimg: "Bot.png",
    title: "il minotauro",
    lore: "Champion Lore"},

    name: "Champ n",
    img: "Alistar.png",
    ip: 1350,
    rp: 585,
    role: "Support",
    roleimg: "Bot.png",
    title: "il minotauro",
    lore: "Champion Lore"}
]};
```

I want to charge this page dynamically when people will click on the list of champions in the other page (I haven't post it here, but it is similar to this, made up with Hanldebar.js too) with a different link for every champions... (for example mysite.com/champion=?champion1).
Can i do it with Javascript (maybe with any external script?), or do you recommend me not to use Wordpress and to make it from scratch?

Comment: this is functionality you have it with yourself first. Stackoverflow is not coding site.Please read guide line how to ask question first.

Comment: You din't help me.

Comment: ok Let me check it first

Comment: whats an issue with this code?If you get anything in console please share here.